# Error writing the project file. Unspecified error

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I try to create new c# project, I get this error:

> Error writing the project file. Unspecified error.

I am using now `VS2015` and I tried to use `VS2013` but I get the same error.

Comment: That looks pretty bad. Try to reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: If the error shows when you try to save it, then try to start VS201x in admin mode. Maybe it is an issue with writing permissions.

Comment: try repairing IIS express

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski .. I did that 3 times

Comment: @mslot .. the error shows when creating the project

Comment: @PandiyanCool .. I'll try

Comment: Actually i have experienced this, and disabling all extensions and such helped!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quote from MDSN blog regarding " What can be done if Visual Studio IDE encounters unexpected problems?"

> When unexpected problems occurs, the key point is trying to isolate
>   potential causes. So it’s good to make the situation as simple as
>   possible.
>
> There are a few things we can try if Visual Studio IDE is not working
>   as expected: a)     Try to run devenv /ResetSettings (in command
>   prompt) to eliminate the related potential settings problem.
>
> b)     Try disabling Add-ins (e.g. “Tools” | “Add-in Manager”) or run
>   “devenv.exe /SafeMode”.This can eliminate the possibility that third
>   party Add-ins or packages are causing problems. (For more detailed VS
>   command line switches information
>
> c)     Try creating a new project. Sometimes corrupted project
>   settings can cause problems. These are project specific.
>
> d)     Make sure that we have the latest service pack applied.
>
> e)     Try to reboot the operating system to safe mode. This can help
>   to isolate whether any other applications are interfering with Visual
>   Studio. Note that some features (like IIS) are not available under
>   safe mode. Please check whether this can be applied or not.
>
> f)      Try to create a new user account. This can help isolate user
>   profile corruption related causes.

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0376db8f-4761-4ae5-9af2-98c53216318a/visual-studio-setup-forum-faqs?forum=vssetup#VS_IDE_unexpected_problems

I hope it will help you sort your issue.